# Interchanging limits and integration for improper Riemann integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

Let $f(x)$ be a function such that the improper Riemann integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\text{d}x$ exists, but where $f$ is not Lebesgue integrable (for example $f(x)=cos(x^2))$. How can I show that for a (smooth) partition of unity $(\beta_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, meanining that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\beta_n(x)=1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, we have
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\text{d}x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)\beta_n(x)\text{d}x$$
You can assume that all $f, \beta_n$ are smooth and bounded. And that each $\beta_n$ has compact support. I have trouble using statements like Fubini or DCT here because $f$ is not integrable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Take $f(x) = \sum_{n \ge 1} (-1)^n \frac{1}{n}1_{[n,n+1)}(x)$ and $\beta_k = 1_{[x_k,x_k+1)}$, where $x_0,x_1,\dots = 2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,1,24,26,\dots,120,122,3,\dots$, where we take odds after we have enough evens to make the sum at least $1/2$. I.e., $$\left(\sum_{k=1}^{11} \frac{1}{2k}\right)-1 > \frac{1}{2}$$ $$\left(\sum_{k=12}^{61} \frac{1}{2k}\right)-\frac{1}{3} > \frac{1}{2},$$ etc.. Then the improper integral of $f$, i.e. $\lim_{L \to \infty} \int_{-L}^L f(x)dx$, exists (since it is just $\lim_{L \to \infty} \sum_{1 \le n \le L} (-1)^n\frac{1}{n}$), but $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_\mathbb{R} f(x)\beta_n(x)dx = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^N \int_\mathbb{R} f(x)\beta_n(x)dx$ does not exist, as we can group consecutive terms to sum to at least $1/2$.

It's easy to make $f$ and the $\beta_k$'s smooth; just make them smooth near the endpoints of the intervals.

Comment: Could you explain how you get $(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{3})+(\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{5})+ ...$? Because I get $(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}-1)+(\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{3})+ ...$
And how do you know that this doesn't converge?

Comment: @LordOfNumbers sorry about that. see updated answer.